# Where to put EF Connection String?

Tags: c#, vb.net, entity-framework

I am working on a project with plugin architecture in VB.NET. I have two projects: **PublicInterfaces** which includes my `IPlugin` interface and some other codes which will be shared on other projects, and **DemoApp** which has a reference to **PublicInterfaces**'s assembly.

My Data model is and `edmx` file is located in **PublicInterfaces**, but in run-time, it gives me an error like this:

> No connection string named 'HRMSApplicationEntities' could be found in the application config file.

while my `App.config` File of **PublicInterfaces** contains it!

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="HRMSApplicationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=HRMSApplication;user id=sa;password=Hamckerma;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

But the strange thing is when I put this into **DemoApp**'s `App.config` file, IT WORKS WITH NO ERRORS!

Where should I put the connection string?

Comment: It goes in the app.config of your entry point (the assembly you are starting your program from).

Comment: The application that builds uses only 1 configuration file.  Whatever project is your start up project should have your app.config and that should have your connection string.  All other app configs wont be used unless you call them specifically.

Comment: simultaneously I and PAQOGOMEZ commented this concept:
found something, if the model and connection string is in 1st project, and 2nd project is a startup project (and have not the connection string), project fails!! 
Maybe because the 1st project has not been initialized!
can be an answer?

Answer (score 1):

When you build **DemoApp**, you will have `DemoApp.exe.config` in *debug/release* folder, which is the application's configuration file. 
**DemoApp** and every referenced dll (including PublicInterfaces.dll) will look in this configuration file. So you only need to add connection string in **DemoApp's** `App.config` file and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes it works, but i don't want to add my connection string on **DemoApp**! because data context should be available in all projects referencing **PublicInterfaces** .

Comment: You can encrypt app.config or create web service (this could be overkill. Depends on your project scenario).

Comment: Temporarily i solved this by another way:
I wrote a partial class of `HRMSDataEntities` and create another constructor which accepts connection string just like his base. then i made my data context in a module with a const connection string and shared it between applications (like DemoApp). it works, but i know it's not the way out...